# Est-ce qu'on écrit « êtes-vous sûrs » ou « êtes-vous sûres » lorsqu'on écrit à un couple ?

Tags: accord, pluriel, genre

Lorsque je m'adresse à un couple (homme/femme) je dois écrire « Êtes-vous sûrs ? » ou « Êtes-vous sûres ? »

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comme le dit cette règle telle que formulée anciennement bien que critiquée pour sa forme aujourd'hui : *le masculin l'emporte sur le féminin*
=> dans une énumération, une liste, un pronom à valeur collective... Au moins un mot masculin => accord de l'adjectif / participe passé au masculin. D'où, pour ton exemple :

*Êtes-vous sûrs ?*

Comment: Merci! une petite question, si je m'adresse à un groupe d'individus composés de femmes et d'hommes, c'est toujours « êtes-vous sûrs ? » ?

Comment: @loki  Oui! Absolument.

Comment: merci :) :) :) :)

Comment: @loki : En revanche, attention dans ton commentaire ci-dessus **c'est le groupe** qui est *compos**é***, pas *les individus*. ;)

Comment: effectivement :) encore merci !